# Hard drives with existing data to NAS

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas

my old d-link 2 failed (hard drives are ok, just the enclosure stopped powering up), so I upgraded to a later product, D-Link DNS-325.  But I am told it can't read existing drives, it will always erase the contents fist.

How can I make D-Link work with existing drives?

Comment: You don't?  While they might be similar products they are not identical. Hopefully, you have a backup of your data you can restore to your new NAS.

Comment: my data is sitll on the 2 hard drives .. they are mirrored. i need to plug them into a network again without wiping

Comment: Hardware RAIDs typically don’t make this possible

Comment: seems like reading of the data should be pretty standard.. what's the best option to get the contents off the drive ?